# Express Can't find Static files

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

Using express and sockets to create a chat client. However I get a 404 when trying to connect to static files.

Server.js

```
var jade = require('jade');

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function() {
    'use strict';
    socket.on('setPseudo', function(data) {
        socket.set('pseudo', data);
    });
    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        socket.get('pseudo', function(error, name) {
            var data = {
                'message': message,
                pseudo: name
            };
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);
            console.log("user " + name + " send this : " + message);
        });
    });
});
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set("view options", {
    layout: false
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    'use strict';
    res.render('home.jade');
});
server.listen(4000);
```

In order for my application to work I need to connect to a script.js file in my /public folder. However the server seem to be unable to find it.

Update with jade file:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title le Chat
        script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js')
        script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        script(src="public/script.js")
body
    div.container
        header
            h1 le Chat Meow
        input(type='text')#pseudoInput
        button#pseudoSet Set Pseudo
        div#chatEntries
        div#chatControls
            input(type='text')#messageInput
            button#submit Send
```

and also the folder structure:

```
-public > script.js
-views > home.jade
-server.js
```

Comment: Can you please paste your HTML code that is requesting for the script.js file and the folder structure of your application?

Comment: Updated with more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `script(src="public/script.js")` to `script(src="script.js")` because your public folder is the root of static files so you dont need to put it in the paths in the html files

Answer (score 0):

Since somebody marked your other newest question about the console.readLine as a dublicate eventhough it obviously wasnt i'l answer to it here instead.

Apparently console.readLine does not work inside an IDE, eclipse for example.
You will have to run the program inside the actual console for that code to work.
A suggestion would be to use a **buffered reader** instead.